Problems with jsmediatags since Firefox 125.0.3
In Firefox, I have a local (i.e. on my harddisk) javascript program (started by a local html and using a local css) that reads info from local csv and json files, it plays audio and video from my local drive and shows several tags from said media files, using jsmediatags.min.js (https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags)
To be able to use mentioned files on this local drive, I had to set the following via about:config in Firefox:
content.cors.disable  set to true
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy  set to false
All was working wonderful until a few days ago, when Firefox 125.0.3 (64-bit) installed itself.
Since then the mediatags are not shown anymore, the jsmediatags error being: “Generic XHR error, check xhr object.“
When I run above mentioned program from the webserver, all is OK, no errors.
Does this mean something in jsmediatags has to be changed, or is there a setting in Firefox’ config that I have to change so that I can run it locally, and if so, which one ?
Thank you very much.
Already searched the web, and Firefox website for this problem, but didn't find anything yet.

You'de be better off running a local webserver than trying to make "unsafe" local files work by turning of security features in your browser. Otherwise it might be best to start switching to something like fetch. However, you should provide us with some code and examples in order for us to replicate your issue.

Most of the time I use this javascript program, I'm not connected to the Internet at all, thus totally running stand-alone. That is the reason I switched off those security settings in FireFox' config.  I did not provide code (yet), because the program has been running without problems for the last 3 years, problem only showed up since Firefox 125.0.3, so my guess was, that there must have been some new or changed setting in Firefox. Therefore my question for Help.

Regarding Fetch: Thanks for the idea, but I'm using the standard jsmediatags.js file which I provide with a media object, and have no intention to start changing (in) this file.

Okay, then check the changelogs of FF or something. If you don't provide any code and are refusing to do anything, I'm unsure why you are even here. If any help provided here is just "don't care, it doesn't work anymore", then what's the point. In all likelihood, FF just doesn't allow you to do that because it simply sounds insecure no matter how you slice it, and it would probably be some security hole. If you have to jump through hoops, why are you surprised it breaks? Clearly dont update your browser if you need things to remain exactly the same.

@somethinghere: When I want to help others with some software questions, I certainly would not use such a crude and almost aggressive style as you did, but hey, not everybody is the same, so I forgive you.
All I asked was more or less if any other user had noticed the same problems accessing local mp3 or mp4 files using jsmediatags.js, and if so, whether they already had a solution. That’s all.
Sorry for not being clear enough the first time around…
I guess I have to ask the Mozilla guys and gals about what change could have created the problems I described.

"I have no intention to follow up on advice given" was the red flag.
